# How to get the lines which are in a particular part

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am a new user to `awk` and I know how to cut columns, append columns and substitute characters. Now I need to cut a particular pattern from a huge file. The file is like below:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = 16384

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
2017-09-08 08:50:04.896 INFO 16323 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.c.c loginCOntroller.java:LOG:Successfully Logged In
```

From this (above is just the head, the file is much bigger), I need to cut all the lines with the pattern:

```
2017-09-08 08:50:04.896 INFO 16323 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.c.c loginCOntroller.java:LOG:
```

I used

```
   sed 's/^.*java:LOG:=//' inpufile > outputfile
```

But it did not work.

Comment: 1) Why do you have a `=` at the end of your search pattern in the `sed` script? The line doesn't contain it. 2) You replace the contents of the line with nothing, so you'll get an empty line there. Use `sed '/java:LOG:/d'`instead to remove the line.

Comment: The use of the word `cut` is ambiguous. Do you want to remove or keep those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/.*java:LOG:/p' inpufile > outputfile
```

Command `sed -n '/pattern/p'` print only strings that **matches with pattern inside** //

Your command - `sed 's/^.*java:LOG:=//'` - uses substitute construction `s/pattern/replace_string/` (looking for a `pattern` and replace it to `replace_string`)

From you example of `sed` command i guess that you need only strings that contain `java:LOG:`. Is this true?

**Pay attention to your filename** - you have missed 't' letter - *inpufile*, but not *inpu**t**file*

If you need exact match with this string:

```
2017-09-08 08:50:04.896 INFO 16323 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] c.c.c loginCOntroller.java:LOG:
```

.. pattern will be too long

Comment: Not working only empty file

Comment: I just need to mathch the LOG: string.Not the whole string

Comment: Oh sorry a typo `sed -n '/.*java LOG:/p' inputfile > outputfile` works fine

Comment: try inpufile, not inputfile in my example. You missed 't' letter in you filename

Comment: Just curious I tried `sed -n '/.* LOG:/p' inputfile > outputfile` works fine.But can I also check the date something like this   `sed -n '/.*2017-09-08* LOG:/p' inputfile > outputfile`.But doesn't works. So basically the command should be able to cut all LOG: pattern startring from the date 2017-09-08.

Comment: pay attention to the file name

Comment: Command sed -n '/.*2017-09-08.*LOG:/p' inpufile > outputfile must work fine

Answer (score 0):

Simply with ***awk*** (to extract the lines by pattern):

```
awk '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*\.java:LOG/' inputfile > outputfile
```